# Howto get a NPAPI plugin on the whitelist?

Tags: npapi, whitelist

Source:
http://www.cio.com/article/740268/Chrome_Will_Block_NPAPI_Plug_ins_Over_Stability_Security_Concerns

"Starting in January 2014, Chrome will block webpage-instantiated NPAPI plug-ins by default on the Stable channel," Schuh said. A temporary exception will be made for the most popular NPAPI plug-ins that are not already being blocked for security reasons in order to avoid disruption to users, he said.

The plug-ins that will be temporarily whitelisted will be Silverlight, Unity, Google Earth, Google Talk and Facebook Video, as they were used by more than 5 percent of users during the past month. Java was used by almost 9 percent of users, but it's already on the list of blocked plug-ins.

"In the short term, end users and enterprise administrators will be able to whitelist specific plug-ins," Schuh said. "Eventually, however, NPAPI support will be completely removed from Chrome."

Question:
Does anyone know how to get a NPAPI plugin on the whitelist ?

Comment: See also: https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2013/09/24/plugin-activation-in-firefox/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, how would you convince the Chromium project to add your plugin to the built-in whitelist? Based on what the blog post says, it sounds like the answer is, "get 5% of Chrome users using it regularly".

If you mean how would you whitelist it within an enterprise, see the [enterprise policy documentation](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/business/browser/admin/).

Note that "blocked by default" essentially means "click to play" (this is covered in other questions here), so if all you are asking is how a user would whitelist a plugin for themselves, see the existing settings for plugins.